# How far can I go with Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a Google Chrome extension, which would have to detect a search form and then contact a server and perform some operations locally. I am a beginner in this field (never programmed an extension before) so I have a couple of questions, because Google Developer Center was not clear enough for me and maybe you can help me out.

How can the browser recognize specific fields when they are clicked by the user? I don't want the exact answer, just a place to start looking/learning. Also, are the extensions capable of performing arithmetic operations?

Cheers,
p312z

Comment: Chrome extensions are programmed in javascript so you should start learning that. And, yes, javascript supports arithmetic operations :P

Comment: "performing arithmetic operations" - well, I think every programming supports that, and with a bit of creativity you can do whatever math you want no matter the (turing-complete) language, too :P

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would most likely be to add event listeners to check and see when the user clicked on specific fields. Although you can't really predict what the fields are going to be called on various websites, there are a few standard words like "address" or "name" that you could have the background script listening for. I would recommend running a quick search for resources related to JavaScript so that you can familiarize yourself with event functions that happen within the browser.

Comment: Thanks Jordan! Yes, I want to check on "standard" fields so I will go for event listeners!

Answer (score 1):

More to the point,  an extension can inject javascript files into any website Page on loading.  Within the injected script,  you can add your own logic: if form,  then check for field id, label, etc.  Then add event listeners accordingly.  The injected script can then talk to the background page as needed. Look at the docs section on 'message passing' in 'implementation'. 
I agree that the docs are incredibly terse.  Their forum link?  Sends you here.  I wish users could comment on the docs,  as in php.net.

Comment: Thanks jCyCle, I will check that out ;) That commenting feature would be great!